# Get Extended Properties for each column

Tags: sql-server, database

Need to modify this query to get the extendeded proerties 'value' column.  I am trying to extend this query to get the description for each column name in the datebase or specific table.

The query below works and I am able to get back the table name, data type and the column name.

```
SELECT        TAB.name AS TableName, TYP.name AS DataTypeName, COL.name AS ColumnName
FROM          sys.columns AS COL INNER JOIN
              sys.tables AS TAB ON COL.object_id = TAB.object_id INNER JOIN
              sys.types AS TYP ON TYP.user_type_id = COL.user_type_id
```

Need to add the sys.extended_properties table but don't know which columns I need to map to get the description value.

Comment: You can find some informations on MSDN site : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/extended-properties-catalog-views-sys-extended-properties?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Not clear if you want the Extended Properties as columns or rows.   If columns, are we talking dynamic or fixed ?

Comment: I need the Extended Properties 'Value' column as an addition column in the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below Query,

```
class=1 -->(1 means object or column),
major_id --> If class is 1,then major_id is object_id,
minor_id --> minor_id is the column_id if column, else 0 if object.
```

(LEFT JOIN is for showing all TABLE,COLUMN DATA irrespective of extended properties)

```
SELECT        TAB.name AS TableName, COL.name AS ColumnName ,TYP.name AS DataTypeName,t.*
FROM          sys.columns AS COL INNER JOIN
              sys.tables AS TAB ON COL.object_id = TAB.object_id INNER JOIN
              sys.types AS TYP ON TYP.user_type_id = COL.user_type_id LEFT JOIN
              sys.extended_properties t on t.major_id=TAB.object_id and t.minor_id=col.column_id and t.class=1
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for and thank you for explaining this as well.  Learned something today!